# .Net export gridview to Excel without word wrapping in Excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview, export-to-excel

I'm exporting a gridview to Excel in .Net. In my gridview there is no word wrap for cells. However when I export it to Excel, there seems to be word wrap for longer text and some rows are higher than others for no reason (no word wrap but still bigger in height).

I've tried the following before calling my `ExportToExcel` method, but they didn't do the trick. Please help. Thanks.

```
//tried this but didn't work
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
   foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
   {
       cell.Wrap = false;
   }
}

//this didn't work either
gv.RowStyle.Wrap = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after your ExportToExcel method:

```
//Select the range of data
selectedRange.EntireRow.AutoFit();
```

Comment: Thanks Koen for the suggestion, but I think your method requires an Excel object. My ExportToExcel method actually uses a HTMLWriter to write the GridView HTML to browser, so it doesn't use an Excel object.

Comment: Then this is indeed not a solution for you.